# Issue with double hashing Java

Tags: java, oop, methods, hashcode, double-hashing

I've been having an issue with a project at university, we have to write a double hash method in a class, which returns a double hashed string object. I thought this would be relatively simple considering the fact that there's an inbuilt hashCode() method in Java, but it seems when you iterate over a hashCode a second time it returns the exact same value. For example:

StringHashCode.java:

```
public class StringHashCode implements HashCode{
    @Override
    public int giveCode(Object obj) {
        return obj.hashCode();
    }
}
```

spell.java

```
while(dict_fwr.hasNextWord())
{
   String derp = dict_fwr.nextWord();
   System.out.print(derp + "(hash value = " + impl.giveCode(derp) + ")" + "(Double hashed = " + impl.giveCode(impl.giveCode(derp)) + ")\n" );
}
```

Excerpt From Output:

```
midwest(hash value = 1055712247)(Double hashed = 1055712247)
partakes(hash value = 1188620491)(Double hashed = 1188620491)
interspersed(hash value = 486466540)(Double hashed = 486466540)
marginally(hash value = 1971567014)(Double hashed = 1971567014)
bemoans(hash value = -223340895)(Double hashed = -223340895)
bankrupt(hash value = -1858199613)(Double hashed = -1858199613)
transpire(hash value = 1052958868)(Double hashed = 1052958868)
conspire(hash value = -567922531)(Double hashed = -567922531)
```

Dict is a file that contains a list of words and the class is a class that was created by out lecturer, it returns the next string and checks whether there is another word.

Comment: The hashcode of an Integer is the integer value.

Comment: What is this HashCode interface you are implementing?

Answer (score 1):

You pass an `int` to `giveCode()`. That gets autoboxed as an Integer. The hash code of the hash code value is the same, because the hash code of an Integer is the integer value. From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#hashCode%28%29):

> **Returns:** a hash code value for this object, equal to the primitive int value represented by this Integer object.

Comment: So how would I go about double hashing it?

Comment: @ConnerStephenMcCabe what are your requirements? If you need a hash code that probably does not collide even when when the built in hash code for two different strings does, you could do something as simple as `("a" + theString).hashCode()`. It's not performant, but usually works. For something more complicated, you could take a look at the source of [String.hashCode()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.hashCode%28%29), and use a different prime from 31.

Comment: Umm, looking at the source, the first suggestion would not work. `theString.length * theString.hashCode()` would for anything that does not have equal lengths. (The latter suggestion should be ok).

Answer (score 1):

You could try hashing the toString of the hashcode:

```
public static int doubleHash(Object obj){
    return new Integer(obj.hashCode()).toString().hashCode();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The primitive type `int` has no method `hashCode` so by default returns itself.

You will have to either write your own hashing method to handle this, or pass the int back in as a class that extends the `Object` class.

[Read up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) on how hashing works to understand better why Integers get parsed into their own primitive form. In short: input values are mapped into a different range of values to represent them. Without a map given to the Integer the value it defaults to the whole integer range, which maps to itself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, the hashCode of an object is an `int`.  When boxing that `int` into an `Integer`, the hashCode returned will just be that `int` again.
To get around this, take the `int` hashCode and make it a String, and then get the hashCode of the second String.
This is what it would look like, step by step, in a main method:

```
public class StringHashCode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // make a String
        String stringToDoubleHash = "Hi There";
        // hashCode of the String
        int hashCode = stringToDoubleHash.hashCode();       
        // String representation of hashCode
        String hashCodeString = Integer.toString(hashCode);
        // hashCode of String representation of first hashCode
        int doubleHash = hashCodeString.hashCode();
        System.out.println(hashCode);
        System.out.println(doubleHash);
    }
}
```

Prints out:

```
623806085
2090143206
```

Adapt above for your needs.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when you swap the "Hi there" for a string object